# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im learning MVC 4. I have created a database first project using EF5. In my edit view I want to add a product number to a customer. When I hit save I get the message below.  I think it is because product number is null in the product table, hence it cannot update. Can I get around this? I have added my edit control

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        UserProfile userprofile = db.UserProfiles.Find(id);
        if (userprofile == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        //ViewBag.userId = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "DeviceIMEI", userprofile.UserId);THIS CREATES A NEW ENTRY IN USERPROFILE TABLE

            ViewBag.Device_DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "DeviceIMEI", userprofile.Device);
            ViewBag.ShippingDetails_ShippingDetailsID = new SelectList(db.ShippingDetails, "ShippingDetailsID", "Address1", userprofile.ShippingDetails_ShippingDetailsID);
            return View(userprofile);

    }

    //
    // POST: /User/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile userprofile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(userprofile).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        //ViewBag.userId = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "DeviceIMEI", userprofile.UserId);
        ViewBag.Device_DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "DeviceIMEI", userprofile.Device);
        ViewBag.ShippingDetails_ShippingDetailsID = new SelectList(db.ShippingDetails, "ShippingDetailsID", "Address1", userprofile.ShippingDetails_ShippingDetailsID);
        return View(userprofile);
    }
```

"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you dont pass `Id` of `UserProfile` from 
view to controller. 
You should add

> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

to your form in view

Comment: ok now I am getting the following error:The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Comment: Ok I hid two field that required date time, that I do not want to edit. This has worked and the application now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're posting a view model, which is disconnected from your entity framework, and trying to tell the EF that it has changed -- which it doesn't know about.  Try something like this instead,

```
var obj = yourContext.UserProfiles.Single(q=>q.Id==userProfile.Id);
obj = userprofile;  // ... Map userprofile to the tracked object, obj
yourContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Sequence contains no elements - This is the error I get when I tried this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.UserProfiles.Attach(userProfile);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but did'nt work, just returned to index and was not in table update.